# Using Bootstrap with Less / Grunt / NOde

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, less, npm

I am reasonably new to Grunt - I have less setup via grunt/node and would like to include the basic unstyled responsive backbone of Bootstrap - rather than the entire css/ js - is this possible - can anyone explain how as i've read various documentation and i'm mighty confused!

I have found this NPM library - https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-bootstrap  which sound slike it could provide what i'm after but I have no idea what files would provide me with the basic responsive skeleton without all the styling - or what version of Boostrap the files relate to - can anyone advise please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the [Bootstrap's source code](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download). Then run `npm install`, after that you can rebuild bootstrap by running the Grunt tasks.

You can disable the jquery Plugins in the `Gruntfile.js` by commenting them out. The same for your CSS code in the `less/bootstrap.less` file.

The `less/bootstrap.less` file already contains useful comments such as `// Reset and dependencies` and `// Core CSS` so it will be easier to find out what to use and what not.

To compile a very basic version that only contains the grid system you could use a `less/bootstrap.less` which contains:

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";

// Reset and dependencies
@import "normalize.less";
@import "print.less";

// Core CSS
@import "grid.less";
```

After changing the `less/bootstrap.less` as above you can run `grunt dist-css`. The preceding command compiles `dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` which can be used for your project.